# How to test secured Endpoints/Rest Controller? Java, with @Secured

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, testing, spring-security

I have a REST Controller, which is secured and needs to be tested:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class ViewerEditorEndpoint {
    private final ViewerEditorService viewerEditorService;

    public ViewerEditorEndpoint(ViewerEditorService viewerEditorService) {
        this.viewerEditorService = viewerEditorService;
    }

    @PutMapping("/{username}")
    @Secured({"ROLE_VOLUNTEER", "ROLE_INDIVIDUAL", "ROLE_COMPANY"})
    UserDTO editAccountInfo(@PathVariable String username, @RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) {
        Optional<UserDTO> oUser= viewerEditorService.editAccountInfo(username, userDTO);
        return oUser.orElse(null);
    }
    @GetMapping("/{username}")
    //@Secured({"ROLE_VOLUNTEER", "ROLE_INDIVIDUAL", "ROLE_COMPANY"})
    UserDTO getAccountInfo(@PathVariable String username) {
        if (username.equals(principal.getName())) {
            return viewerEditorService.getAccountInfo(username).orElse(null);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I tried it with @WithMockUser, @WithUserDetails, but none really works. I saw a lot of examples with Mockmvc but I don't really understand how to implement this. I would appreciate some tipps(:

Comment: (1) `@Secured` has been outdated in favor of `@PreAuthorize` for at least ten years. (2) You use `@WithMockUser`, `@WithUserDetails`, or similar. "None really works" does not give us any information to work with to help you.

Comment: thanks, ok to clarify ma situation a bit more, I researched and tried some things for several hours and I did not understand the explanation that I found online. Thats why I cant really tell you what I tried allready. I just wanted to ask, if someone out there has a solution that somehow works. regarding the @Secured/@PreAuthorize, I changed it to the secound one but, then the security of the endpoint does not work anymore, everbody can log in, also the people that have the wrong authorization.

Comment: Tried _what_ things? What happened, specifically, when you tried them? What does your security configuration look like (e.g., do you have `prePostEnabled = true`)?